# How can I get a bootloader with WIndows 8 and LinuxMint

Tags: grub

I have Windows 8, then I would install Linux Mint with USB live so i created partitions /home, / and swap then i started the installation.

But after the restarting i still dont see any bootloader to select between WIndows and LInuxMint 17

Here is my boot-info :       http://pastebin.com/GgWBPq7J
SO how can i get a bootloader ?

Comment: Do you have no boot-loader entries at all? Don't you have access to your knew Linux Mint system?

Comment: i have no bootloader, when i turn on the computer its just go on Windows 8. but i start an USB live of Linux Mint

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, noobie here (69 yr young)! The point in case is: you first need to Unlock UEFI (Secure boot in BIOS) and allow 'Other OS', switch the `Fast boot` option off, next start into Win 8 (.1) and shutdown Win *completely* pressing keyboard `WinKey + R` to go into the Command Terminal and type: `shutdown -s -t` (mind spaces).
If no cigar and back in Win (provided you have Linux already installed) go to MS Recover->Troubleshoot->Advanced Options->Startup Settings to `evt`. Initialize a Live Linux Mint USB pendrive or DVD. Next: repeat the install procedure.
When succeeding in seeing the boot loader with Mint and Win, you'll need to press `e` first to edit the line starting with "Linux". At the end of it and before `--` add `nomodeset pci=nocrs pci=realloc`, next `F10` to start Linux. If you don't do this you might get a "black screen" and again no cigar!
Repeat this of course in `/root/boot/grub/grub.cfg` !!!!! Otherwise you'll need to type the above code over and over again... That's it in a very nutshell.